# Входящие соединения для приложения

Tags: iptables

Имеется сервер на Ubuntu Linux. На сервере крутится демон с именем, например, `daemon_bin`. Демон слушает сетевой порт, но этот порт в общем случае неизвестен. Можно считать, что прослушиваемый порт открывается по запросу и имеет случайный номер.

Можно ли добавить в *iptables* правило, которое будет пропускать входящие соединения только в том случае, когда они адресованы этому демону?

P.S. Предложения дать демону определённый диапазон портов и разрешить входящие для этого диапазона не предлагать. Отключение файрвола также не вариант.

Comment: В принципе есть модуль owner, который позволяет по uid/gid процесса определять трафик. но он только на OUTPUT работает, так что полуоткрытые соединения от левых машин скорее всего будут задерживаться.

Comment: Еще как вариант сделать скрипт который включить в стартовые скрипты демона, который определит порт и добавит правило. Но тогда вопрос как удалять старые правила при перезапуске демода ил не дай бог если он порт меняет на ходу

Comment: @Mike `owner` смотрел. Он только на выход, как я понял. Порт определить не получится, демон его меняет в процессе работы. Динамический, зараза!

Comment: Вообще его все и предлагают. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314163/create-iptables-rule-per-process-service  Что то установилось TCP соединение надо что бы прошел двухсторонний обмен. Теоретически ответные пакеты от сервиса пройдут через OUTPUT и их заблочат или пропустят. Но если заблочить ответные пакеты мне кажется могут начать подвисать полуоткрытые соединения, как я писал выше. В общем я бы предложил попробовать. Разумеется на INPUT при этом придется разрешить все входящие TCP, а на OUTPUT заблочить все лишнее. Для тестов можете дианазон некий открыть и попробовать посоединятся

Comment: Не могу сообразить, а как клиенты к демону подключаются, если порт заранее не известен?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit Клиент соединяется с демоном по заранее известному порту, после чего демон специально для этого клиента открывает другой порт, сообщает его клиенту по первому соединению, после чего закрывает первое соединение. Типа пассивного FTP, но всё шифровано и внутрь протокола не заглянуть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я понял, то доступа к сорцам скрипта нет. Поэтому, нужно действовать в обход.  Для начала берем ltrace (или, возможно, strace) и запускаем приложение под ним. Если только там ничего не перестарались, то приложение будет дергать библиотечнык функции для открытия/закрытия сокетов. Убеждаемся, что вызовы проходят. Например, для бинда порта ожидается увидеть где то такое

```
bind(3, 0x7ffd828bc018, 16, 8080)  = 0
```

теперь нужно будет найти "парные вызовы". Скорее всего это будет listen/close или bind/close.

Следующий этап - код. Берем любой пример, который показывает, как перехватывать вызовы к сокетам, я нашел [здесь](https://cwrap.org/socket_wrapper.html) и оставляем только нужные нам вызовы. В "открывающей функции" можно подсмотреть номер порта и дескриптор сокета (это первое число). Сохраняем эту пару где нибудь себе (в хеш, в файл, в базу) и вызываем iptables, что бы он открыл нужный порт. В закрывающей функции по дескриптору находим порт и закрываем правило в iptables.
В результате будет одна so'шка, которая будет подгружаться через `LD_PRELOAD`.